# PasteSpecial and InputBox error code 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy AutoFilter and  pastespecial to range I take from inputbox
put I getting 1004 error, any ideas?

```
 Sub CopyFiltred2()
Dim StartCell As Range
Dim StartCell2 As Range
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Copy


Set StartCell = Excel.Application.InputBox("Range?" & vbNewLine & "Please select the cell:" _
                                , "Insert Table of Contents", , , , , , 8)

StartCell.Select
Selection.PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the range selected by the line `ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Copy`? If the range selected is not found you receive the error 1004.

Also you don't need to select the cell before using `PasteSpecial`.

Replace :

```
StartCell.Select
Selection.PasteSpecial
```

by :

```
Range(StartCell).PasteSpecial Paste:=PasteAll
```